# Automation Anywhere Workbench: No output file after running PDF Integration

Tags: automationanywhere

The following action

`PDF Integration: Extract Text from file.pdf to output.txt`

doesn't output the expected file after execution. What can go wrong? Are there log messages that can provide clue?

Comment: It so happened the PDF contains only images and no text. It'll be nicer to have an empty output file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since your PDF contains only images, you can extract the PDF to Image then use OCR command to read the text from the image.